# Is there any difference between enumerable and own properties?

Tags: javascript

> The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties
>   from a source object to a target object.

This quote is taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). My understanding was that enumerable properties and own properties were the same.  So, what is the difference between them? Thank you.

Comment: own properties can be made non-enumerable, like with Object.defineProperty() for example.

Comment: Two different things. Own properties are on the object itself, they don't come from the prototype. Enumerable properties are those shown when you do anything like `for(var prop in obj)`

Comment: @VLAZ could you provide some code examples ?

Comment: Well, `.prototype` is a property on each object but you won't get it from `for (var prop in obj)` or `Object.keys(obj)`, and so on. It's not enumerable. Basically it's "hidden" from enumeration. Exactly like the name suggests. You can still access non-enumerable properties explicitly: `obj.prototype`.

Comment: @VLAZ ok, i understand the difference between enumerable and not-enumerable. But i still don't get difference between own and enumerable.

Comment: @VLAZ ok , for example i have an `obj = {a : 2}` . Isn't it correct to say that `obj.a` is own property of `obj` and enumerable at the same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enumerabilty and ownership of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) are orthogonal to each other. There are enumerable own properties, non-enumerable own properties, enumerable inherited properties and non-enumerable inherited properties.

The "and" in the MDN quote signifies that a property must **both** be *owned* and be *enumerable* to be copied by `Object.assign` - in short, it copies own enumerable properties.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i understood  the difference.

Comment: I'm trying to find example of each of possibilities you mentioned: `enumerable own properties, non-enumerable own properties, enumerable inherited properties and non-enumerable inherited properties`
So if I have an object `obj = {a:1, b: 2};` then `a` and `b` are `enumerable own`, if I do `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'c', {'value': 4})` then `c` is `non-enumerable own` and `obj.toString` is an example of `non-enumerable inherited`.
What is an example of `enumerable inherited` property?

Comment: @D_S_X `Object.prototype.d = 3` - but don't do that for obvious reasons :-)

Comment: @Bergi Why shouldn't we do that?

Comment: I mean `Object.prototype` specifically - it breaks many things. For other prototypes, it's standard practice.